# Fill a cell with color even if nothing is returned

Tags: heatmap, reportbuilder

I am trying to create a risk heat map in MS Report Builder. The heat map is a 5X5 grid for each combination of 5 levels of likelihood and 5 levels of impact. The goal is to show risk ID numbers (if any) in each of the 25 boxes depending on likelihood and impact level. I have accomplished this to the extent that risk IDs do show up in relevant boxes. However, I want a predetermined background color for each of the 25 boxes. For now, the background color is applied only around the risk ID text, not the entire area.

Here is what I want to do, with all cells filled with a color regardless of whether any value is returned.

[image]

And here is what I have been able to do.

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! I placed a rectangle in each of the 25 boxes, and filled each rectangle with the color I wanted. I then inserted a single cell table in each rectangle (so 25 tables in total). Each table brings up IDs of risks that belong to that box, and has a fill color that matches color of the rectangle.